# Saving output of for loop to df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm a newbie at Python, so sorry in advance for the ignorance. I am trying to pull specific exif data from a directory that will ultimately have thousands of images. I want to pull a specific text item (camera make) and place it in a df column. The other df column of that df will store the filename of the respective picture. As of now, I can get the the camera make to print as a list inside the for loop. Is there an easy way to write this directly to that dataframe?

```
for x in df.Filename:
    image = Image.open(x)
    exifdata = image.getexif()
    exif = {
        PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
        for k, v in image._getexif().items()
        if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
    }
    y=(exif.get('Make'))
    
    print(y)
```

Comment: You can store your results of each pass in a simple list.  Then after the loop, you can convert your list to a df column.

Answer (score 0):

Consider re-writing your process as a method and call it with `Series.apply` (hidden loop). Consider also using `with` context manager to proper close [`Image` object](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) after use and remove unused lines.

```py
def get_camera_make(f):
    with Image.open(f) as img:
        exif = {
            PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
            for k, v in img._getexif().items()
            if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
        }

    return exif.get('Make')
    
# ASSIGN NEW COLUMN
df["Camera_Make"] = df["Filename"].apply(get_camera_make)
```